# xfs incremental backup doesn't fit new disk

Tags: copy, xfs, block

I have a 1TB xfs volumne on Amazon EBS, which contains 246GB of incremental backups, created with rsync and hardlinking. I want to copy this to a new, smaller disk.

The problem is it doesn't seem to fit into a 300GB disk. Is there any block size that I can investigate or something?
I have recently removed 700GB of backups, do I need to clear something off? I'm using cp -R to copy between  the mounted volumes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using cp -R to copy your hardlinked data is removing the hardlinks.

```
$ du -sh one/ two/
140M    one
4.0K    two
$ cd one
~/one$ ln file1 file2
~/one$ ls -s
total 285280   
142640 file1  142640 file2
$ cd ..  
$ du -sh one two  
140M    one
4.0K    two
```

At this point ls shows two 140MB files, but they are hard linked, so du reports just 140MB in use.

```
$ cp -R ../one/* two/
$ du -sh one two
140M    one
279M    two
```

This shows that cp -R doesn't preserve the hardlink status.

The (or at least, one) right way to copy this is to use rsync again, with the -H (or --hard-links) parameter.

```
rsync -avPH one/ three
sending incremental file list
./
file2
   146058808 100%  185.43MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=0/3)
file1 => file2

sent 146076781 bytes  received 47 bytes  292153656.00 bytes/sec
total size is 292117616  speedup is 2.00
$ ls -s three/
total 285272  
142636 file1  142636 file2
$ du -sh three
140M    three
```